# Dead-simple USB-based Windows partition cloner?

Tags: windows, usb-flash-drive, disk-cloning

Clonezilla is a fine open-source tool, but it requires going through several screens.

Since I need to save/restore the same Windows partition, I was wondering if someone knew of a tool (open-source or not) that is easier to use and boots off a USB keydrive.

Ideally, it'll save the two commands to save/restore a partition, so I just need to boot the host from the USB key, choose the command, and it'll take care of business.

Are there solutions that look like this?

Thank you.

---

Edit: [Here](https://serverfault.com/questions/168880/script-to-automate-clonezilla-to-create-a-bootable-image-on-usb)'s one among other articles that shows how to tell CZ to run a script to avoid the multiple screens.

Comment: You do understand you can automate a Clonezilla backup right?

Comment: Thanks for the idea. I'll investigate how to configure Linux to start CZ automatically and have it run a script.

Answer (score 1):

**XXClone** is supposed to be very good (however I dont think its available as a portable)

http://www.xxclone.com/

Otherwise Clonezilla Portable:

http://clonezilla.org/liveusb.php

Alernatively O&O Disk Image (paid for version,again I dont think its portable):

http://www.oo-software.com/en/products/oodiskimage/

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using Windows Backup? It allows you to choose to create a full system image that you can easily restore from within the control Panel Later.